# How do I serve static files in Express using VS code?

Tags: javascript, express, visual-studio-code

Please be patient, I'm new at this. I've set up myapp using this tutorial - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial and now I'm trying to serve static files using this tutorial - https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html, but I'm getting errors and I'm lost as to how to fix them. The errors are below. Please help and thank you!

```
express.static : The term 'express.static' is not recognized 
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was   
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.        
At line:1 char:9
+ app.use(express.static('public'))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (express.static:  
  String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: you are trying to run a javascript file as a PowerShell script,

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to execute a fragment of JS as a PowerShell script.

JS isn't PowerShell so it errors.

You need to:

1. create a JS file
2. build the basics of an Express.js based server in it (see the [Hello World example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) on the Express.js website)
3. add the static middleware to that program
4. [execute that JS file using node.js](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial#_running-hello-world)